# Magento 2 - Override Reorder controller and skip some items from reorder

Tags: reorder, order-items, magento2.2.9

**I have to skip some items when the customer does Reorder. For this, I have overridden the controller Using Plugin.**

> di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Controller\AbstractController\Reorder">
        <plugin name="reorder" type="MyModule\MyReorder\Plugin\Reorder" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

> Controller File

```
<?php

namespace MyModule\MyReorder\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\Registry;

class Reorder
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart
     */
    private $cart;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Controller\AbstractController\OrderLoaderInterface
     */
    private $orderLoader;
    /**
     * @var Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Controller\AbstractController\OrderLoaderInterface $orderLoader,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
        Registry $registry
    ) {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        $this->orderLoader = $orderLoader;
        $this->cart = $cart;
    }
    public function aroundExecute(
        \Magento\Sales\Controller\AbstractController\Reorder $subject,
        $result
    ){
    }
    public function afterExecute(
        \Magento\Sales\Controller\AbstractController\Reorder $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        $order = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_order');
        $cart = $this->cart;
        $reorderid =  $order->getIncrementId();
        $quote = $cart->getQuote();
        $quote->setReOrderId($reorderid);
        $cart->save();

        return $result;
    }
}
```

**Please help me how to skip product with some ID in around Method.**

Answer (score 0):

**This is the actual code in class:**

```
    /**
     * Action for reorder
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $result = $this->orderLoader->load($this->_request);
        if ($result instanceof \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface) {
            return $result;
        }
        $order = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_order');
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();

        /* @var $cart \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart */
        $cart = $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart::class);
        $items = $order->getItemsCollection();
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            try {
                $cart->addOrderItem($item);
            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
                if ($this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session::class)->getUseNotice(true)) {
                    $this->messageManager->addNoticeMessage($e->getMessage());
                } else {
                    $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
                }
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/history');
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addExceptionMessage(
                    $e,
                    __('We can\'t add this item to your shopping cart right now.')
                );
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('checkout/cart');
            }
        }

        $cart->save();
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('checkout/cart');
    }
```

and you are trying to do something on this action: `$cart->addOrderItem($item);`

I think you can try adding your logic in the method -

> `addOrderItem($orderItem, $qtyFlag = null)`

**If you see the method it has the below code:**

```
    /**
     * Convert order item to quote item
     *
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item $orderItem
     * @param true|null $qtyFlag if is null set product qty like in order
     * @return $this
     */
    public function addOrderItem($orderItem, $qtyFlag = null)
    {
If you see the method it has the below code:
        /* @var $orderItem \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item */
        if ($orderItem->getParentItem() === null) {
            $storeId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
            try {
                /**
                 * We need to reload product in this place, because products
                 * with the same id may have different sets of order attributes.
                 */
                $product = $this->productRepository->getById($orderItem->getProductId(), false, $storeId, true);
            } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
                return $this;
            }
            $info = $orderItem->getProductOptionByCode('info_buyRequest');
            $info = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject($info);
            if ($qtyFlag === null) {
                $info->setQty($orderItem->getQtyOrdered());
            } else {
                $info->setQty(1);
            }

            $this->addProduct($product, $info);
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

you can add before on this public method and throw exception from there.
The exception will be caught in the controller class and the loop will go to next item. 
**Hope it helps to add the logic you are trying to add**

Answer (score 0):

Check original `execute()` and there you will found `foreach ($items as $item) {`

And inside this `foreach loop` you can sky the item which you want to skip

Like

```
$items = $order->getItemsCollection();
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            try {
               $orderItemSku = $item->getSku();
               $orderItemproductId = $item->getProduct();
                 /// SKip Product which has id 150
                 if(orderItemproductId == 150){
                    continue;
                 }
                $cart->addOrderItem($item);

        ......
```

Comment: Hi @amit yes I have checked there in controller. Can you please help me to override this in my controller?

Comment: I have already overriden one thing in my controller.

Comment: can you please help?